# Calculate voltage and amp drop of resistance

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, series, ohms-law

How do i calculate the voltage and amperage drop from resistance on a DC series circuit?

I know ohm's law and all, but I’m doubting how much of actually applies to this equation, since i know the voltage, current and resistance

I have googled all over the place and have only found indirect ohms Law equations where either voltage, current and resistance have to be missing

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX8eqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111120/discussion-on-question-by-samuel-walker-calculate-voltage-and-amp-drop-of-resist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know ohm's law and all, but I’m doubting how much of actually applies to this equation, since i know the voltage, current and resistance

As stated in the comments, you *don't* know the voltage, current, and resistance. Also Ohm's law only defines the behavior of a resistor, i.e. it only defines the behavior of R2 in your circuit.

I think the key thing that needs to be clarified is that the task here is to *determine the voltage and current for each individual component within the circuit*. In other words we wish to determine the battery voltage and current, the resistor voltage and current, and the diode voltage and current. Without going deep into theory, we can state that the current through the resistor and diode is equal, and is the same as the current supplied by the battery. We can also say that the voltage dropped across the resistor, plus the voltage dropped across the diode, is equal to the battery source voltage.

Your battery is specified as "14.8V 60A", but what this means is that your source *will drive a source voltage of 14.8V, for any output current up to 60A*. So we know the source voltage (14.8V!) and we just need to figure out how much current it's sourcing. (Let's just assume that the current is less than 60A, since 60A would vaporize your wires and land you in the hospital.)

Let's just sidestep all that awesome math from EE school and ask the real question of "will this circuit work, or will the components fail?"  The [LTL-307EE datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf) tells us that this device can operate at a maximum continuous current of 30mA. (Side note: electrical engineers know that "maximum rating" = "really pushing your luck, don't actually do this" but we'll do this for our analysis.)

If the current through the circuit was 30mA, then the voltage drop across the LED would be about 2.1V (refer to Fig 2 of the datasheet) and the voltage drop across the resistor would be 100 ohms * 30mA = 3V (Ohm's law). So the total voltage dropped across those components would be 5.1V at 30mA, far less than the 14.8V sourced by the battery. When the battery is supplying 14.8V instead of just 5.1V, then the actual current through the circuit will be much higher than this hypothetical 30mA. It's tricky to pin down the exact value due to the strange relationship between LED voltage and LED current, but we don't care about the exact value here -- we know that the circuit will fail. Any other details are unimportant.

So, how could we modify this to work? Well, the analysis above just told us that a 5.1V battery would push 30mA through this circuit, which could work well. Better yet, let's just increase the value of R2 as SolarTec suggested. Looking at the LTL-307EE datasheet again, we see a maximum continuous current of 30mA and the test conditions specified as 20mA. *The vendor is telling us that 20mA is really the correct value to be working at*, so let's shoot for that.

If the current through the circuit is 20mA, and the LED voltage drop is 2V at 20mA per the datasheet, then we need a resistor that will drop the remaining (14.8V - 2V) = 12.8V when 20mA is flowing through it. Again, per Ohm's law, 12.8V / 0.02A = 640Ω.

Answer (score 0):

Diode forward voltage = 2V.

Current = (14.8 - 2) / 100  = 128mA. Too high for that LED rated at a maximum of 120mA. You should increase your resistor value.

Comment: Per the datasheet note that the *continuous* (i.e. DC) maximum current is actually 30mA. The 120mA you cite only applies to a 1/10 duty cycle, 0.1ms pulse width signal. Also the forward voltage will be higher than 2V per fig 2 of the datasheet. But these revised numbers do not change the fact that the circuit won't work, and needs to be modified.